# can not find list control when adding a list to a web page

Tags: list, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I have created a list in top level site. And I want to use the list in a child site (e.g. adding the list to a page in child site by using Page --> Add Web Parts --> Browse), but can not find the list created in parent site in this way. Any ideas how to use the list (created in parent site) in a child site?

BTW: I can use the list (created in parent site) in parent site without any issues.

Comment: @George2: Can you please review your older questions and check for any that should be marked as answered? If you haven't received the answers you'd like, please edit and clarify your questions. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Content Query Web Part.

Comment: Thanks Anders! Could you show me more information about how to use "Content Query Web Part" to create a list which could be showed in both parent site and child site (to show the same content)?

Comment: @George You might need to open a New Question for this. But I will give you answer here for Content Query Web Part.
http://blogs.msdn.com/ecm/archive/2006/10/25/configuring-and-customizing-the-content-query-web-part.aspx

Comment: yeah sorry was in a hurry on way to a meeting! thx kusek